# Local notifications not working in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to Ionic 3 and I implemented Local notifications using plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/ and it works just as expected, but every time I push my changes and take a pull again, I need to re-install the plugin and build again.
Any solutions?

Comment: I got the fix, it was this line in my **package.json** file that was causing the problem:

`"cordova-plugin-app-event": "file:node_modules/cordova-plugin-app-event"`

Changing the path of the plugin fixed the issue.

Comment: Wait, did you mean.. I have to add that line in package.json ?

Comment: That line already existed in **package.json**, only the path was incorrect, i.e, when I went to the given path, the directory wasn't there but one more step inside, and that was the issue.
What I did back then was to move the directory out to the given path, and that worked.
One more thing to do could be to remove your **node_modules** directory and then running `npm i`
Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, I see.. thanks!

Comment: No problem, always happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the **first comment** in my question itself, the problem was resolved, so I am closing this topic by posting an answer.

I got the fix, it was this line in my **package.json** file that was causing the problem: 
`"cordova-plugin-app-event": "file:node_modules/cordova-plugin-app-event"`Changing the path of the plugin fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987144/how-do-i-send-local-notifcation-in-ionic-3), the correct way to install local notification plugin for Ionic 3 is by using `ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification`

Most Ionic 3 users have CLI version 3 and above. Hope this help to others too!

Comment: The correct way, as given in [Official Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/), was followed and everything was working fine.
The problem was different than what you are trying to solve.
Maybe it was a temporary issue, as it does not happen anymore.